# Windows command to copy file forcefully when that file is used by another process

Tags: windows-xp, automation

I am copy a file using `copy` command. But its throwing some error.

```
copy /y ..\BuildLog.htm .
```

Error is : `The process cannot access the file because its used by another process`

`XCOPY /Y` is also throwing error. Is there any way to copy the file successfully. I have checked the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264231/is-there-any-way-to-force-copy-copy-without-overwrite-prompt-using-windows) related to this but this is not helping.

Note : I am doing this on WinXP SP3

Comment: While file is in use, the source or the destination?

Comment: source file is used by another process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647701/how-to-copy-in-use-files-through-batch-file-in-windows-7) by [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) your solution is with very high probability [hobocopy](http://candera.github.io/hobocopy/)

Comment: Of course, this solution doesn't exist anymore